# Create an aggregate column in python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I'm new to python and I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
d = {'1-1.a': ["Yes", ""], '1-1.b': ["No", ""],'1-1.c':["Yes","Yes"],'1-1.d':["",""],'2-1.a':["Yes","No"]}
d = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and I want to create a new column called Q1 where it's an aggregate of columns 1-1.a-d and looks like the following:

```
e = {'1-1.a': ["Yes", ""], '1-1.b': ["No", ""],'1-1.c':["Yes","Yes"],'1-1.d':["",""],'1-Q1':["a,c","c"],'2-1.a':["Yes","No"]}
e = pd.DataFrame(data=e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `dot`

```
d['Q1'] = d.eq('Yes').dot(d.columns.str.split('.').str[1]+',').str[:-1]
Out[159]: 
0    a,c
1      c
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution but I updated the question, in my data frame there could be multiple columns with a . separator

Comment: and I get the following error when I run: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: @Mel in SO , we can only based on what you have in sample data and expected output to offer the solution. Please check your real data find the different.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I updated the sample data. Is there a quick solution for that? thank you!

Comment: @Mel filter the dataframe before do dot, like d1=d.filter(like='1-1')

Comment: Like this? d['Q1'] = d.eq('Yes').filter(like='1-1').dot(d.columns.str.split('.').str[1]+',').str[:-1]

Comment: I get an error when I do that in the sample dataset

Comment: @Mel  d1=d.filter(like='1-1') ; d['Q1'] = d1.eq('Yes').dot(d1.columns.str.split('.').str[1]+',').str[:-1]